# When the file change in amazon s3, the file not change in amazon cloutfront

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I use amazon s3 for image storage. I can upload any file, this is very good. But when i delete or update image in s3, cloutfront still hold old image.

How can i change cloutfront image file?

I use php with codeigniter. I use [this library](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i found the solution.

If i change file Cache-Control value like this max-age=SECOND, cloutfront refresh cache every SECOND for this file.

Detail information: [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)

And for php users, s3 library options: [Library](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#putObject)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the TTL of the cloudfront to low minimum available. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not solved :/ i change ttl 10 seconds but still working same.